# ORA-12170: TNS: Connect timeout occurred in oracle 10g using sql plus

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am new to oracle, I have installed the oracle 10g with sql plus. I used sql plus yesterday but now it is giving me this error **ORA-12170: TNS: Connect timeout occurred** at the time of login. I am using **SCOTT User** for login.

I am using these credentials for login:

**username: Scott**

**password: tiger**

**host: orcl**

I have googled it already and tried some solution but it doesn't work :(

Here are some details about my configuration:

**sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
 )
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.9)(PORT = 1521))
)
)
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.9)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
)
)

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = PLSExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping 192.168.1.9. If that works, try

```
tnsping orcl
```

from the command line. Maybe there is a firewall that blocks your network access to the Oracle DB?